# Visual Studio 2010: Using define macro to specify output executable

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, build, compilation

I need to use a #define macro that is defined in a header file to be used in the specification of the output file.

To specify what I need, a have a header.hpp file with the entry #define VERSION 12 and want the output myProgram_12.exe. Is there a way to accomplish that in Visual Studio 2010 without changing the project propperties by hand.

Comment: don't do this, go the other way around: set a property in the build system and use that where required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the authoritative source of information on the version number is the `#define`, then I'm afraid there is no easy solution, but it could be done with an ugly-ish workaround.

You could create a tool which would extract the version number from the header and write it into a Visual Studio property sheet (`.vsprops`) file, which would be included in your project (in the `Property Manager`). That tool could actually be a C++ program that would `#include` the header (or at least launch such a program to obtain the number).

Of course, the tool should probably cache the value and only re-write the property sheet when it differs, so that you don't get constant rebuilds when you hook the tool into your build chain.

Comment: +1 there's no way to get the content of a file into the build system without manually parsing it. Hence things become ugly.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you to use following code,
In your .h file

```
#define VERSION2
```

In your .cpp file

```
' add reference to Microsoft.VisualStudio.VCProjectEngine
Imports EnvDTE
Imports Microsoft.VisualStudio.VCProjectEngine

Public Module Module1
    Sub Test()
        Dim prj As VCProject
        Dim cfgs, tools As IVCCollection
        Dim cfg As VCConfiguration
        Dim tool As VCLinkerTool
        prj = DTE.Solution.Projects.Item(1).Object
        cfgs = prj.Configurations
        cfg = cfgs.Item(1)
        tool = cfg.Tools("VCLinkerTool")
       #ifdef VERSION2
        tool.OutputFile = "$(ProjectName).exe"
        #ifdef VERSION3
        tool.OutputFile = "$(ProjectName1).exe"
    End Sub
End Module
```

Its VB code but you can easily converted it into VC++ code by using this link [How to: Compile Example Code for Project Model Extensibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/2ya384e0%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)